# Illegal invocation when Post request an image

Tags: jquery, ajax, http-post

I'm trying to do a post request with an image, but I keep getting following error when I add it as a parameter `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`. I've tried this and `.serialize()`, but nothing seems to work.

```
  var description = $('#description').val();
  var title = $('#title').val();

  var fileInput = $("#image")[0];

  var file = fileInput.files[0];
  var image = new FormData();
  image.append('image', file);

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert.php',
    data: {
        desc: description,
        title: title,
        image:image,
        longitude: currentMarker.lng(),
        longitude: currentMarker.lat(),
           },
          success: function (answer) {

          }
      })
```

Comment: add this `processData: false, // tell jQuery not to process the data
                contentType: false, // tell jQuery not to set contentType` in your ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put `FormData` into one of the parameters being sent, it has to be the entire `data` value. So it should be:

```
var image = new FormData();
image.append('image', file);
image.append('desc', description);
image.append('title', title);
image.append('longitude', currentMarker.lng());
image.append('latitude', currentMarker.lat());
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert.php',
    data: image,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(answer) {
        ...
    }
});
```

When sending `FormData`, you need to tell jQuery not to try to convert the data argument from an object to a URL-encoded string with `processData: false`.